# Why does the Basic AUTH box repeatedly pop up after providing a correct user/pw?

Tags: php, .htaccess, cgi, basic-authentication, fastcgi

I'm writing a very simple authorization script that just uses a PHP header to prevent non-admins from accessing other sites.  This PHP script is just called authorize.php and is included in other files via

```
<?php require_once('authorize.php'); ?>
```

before the remaining HTML code.

Here's the script:

```
<?php
//User name and password for authentication
$username = 'rock';
$password = 'roll';
//these arent the real passwords of course...

if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) || !isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) || ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] != $username) || ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] != $password)) {
//The user name/password are incorrect so send the authentication headers
header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm= "Guitar Wars" ');
exit('<h2>Guitar Wars</h2>Sorry, but you do not have permission to view this page');
}
?>
```

And that's it.  It's not fancy at all, but for some reason entering the user/pw correctly simply causes the AUTH box to pop up again every time.

I sniffed around for an answer, and although I found some similar problems, none really solved it. For example: 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908394/why-is-it-that-when-i-use-http-authentication-with-php-it-doesnt-close-until-i)
but my headers ARE in the if statement...
or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20204265/admin-username-password-isnt-working-for-php)
in which the question wasn't really answered...
I even tried entering this..

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

into the .htaccess of the root directory based on something else I found, but that didn't help and I honestly don't even know what it does...

I did check my php info, looks like its CGI/fastCGI.

What is wrong here?  I've pretty much copied the code verbatum out of the textbook I'm learning from (I'm an English professor, not a programmer mind you so please be gentle with me)

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to my problem after 2 days of searching... My above idea of editing the .htaccess file was only partially right.  I needed to include this in the .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
</IfModule>
```

and then in my PHP script, above where I made the headers, include this:

```
if(preg_match('/Basic+(.*)$/i', $_SERVER['REDIRECT_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'], $matches))
{
list($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'], $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) = explode(':' , base64_decode(substr($_SERVER['REDIRECT_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'], 6)));
}
```

I'm just a beginner so I have absolutely no clue what any of that does, but hey, it fixed the problem.  If others are having this issue, allow me to elaborate on some other things I noticed so you can compare your situation to mine.

1. I have an ipage account and that's what I'm doing all this on. It seems to be Apache 2.
2. phpinfo shows that it's running FastCGI/CGI
3. Calling a var_dump on $_SERVER did not show either the PHP_AUTH_USER or the PHP_AUTH_PW indexes, although it did show REMOTE_USER, which seemed to store at least the username input.
4. I found the answer [here.](http://www.rosmir.org/Index/Docs/archive/LabsFolder/FastCGI)